# how to find out html textfield field focus in .js file

Tags: javascript

i want find html textfield blur or focus through .js file

Comment: can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: Do you want to know which textfield has the focus or detect if a textfield is focused or not?

Comment: yes, please clarify your question, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for javascript events?

> onFocus, onBlur and onChange
>
> The onFocus, onBlur and onChange events are often used in combination with validation of form fields.

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_events.asp